# Add world map in which each country is clickable and show some data in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to add a map to my App, in which I want to make every country clickable independently, and It shows some data in form of a Piechart. I'm a beginner in App development, can anyone help me with any kind of suggestions....

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add markers in your map by setting latlongs(of all the countries) to the markers. And set `setOnMarkerClickListener` to the map.